# Visual Studio Community: Delete lines prefixed by a line feed

Tags: visual-studio

In this code
[image]
I'd like to delete the line 2207 **and** 2208.

I tried several replace actions in the "Search & Replace" tools but none works

- `\r\n                WriteDumbowLog("MethodName:" & methodName)"`
- `"\n\r                WriteDumbowLog("MethodName:" & methodName)"`
- `".$                WriteDumbowLog("MethodName:" & methodName)"`
- `"\n                WriteDumbowLog("MethodName:" & methodName)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct regular expression is:

`((\r\n)|\n|\r)                WriteDumbowLog\("MethodName\:" & methodName\)`

I used this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace which doesn't work (oddly) but provide you the correct regex to replace.